# Progress Bar(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the progress bar working. On each input(First Name, Last Name, Full Name, Type your password, Retype your password), the progress should go from 0% to 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%. if a input field is blank, for each input it will not add 20% from the progress-bar. You can see the progress-bar at top of the web page.

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

#Black{
       width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
   }

#White{
       width:600px;
    height:auto;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    color:white;
    margin:100px auto;
   }   
   
#Prog{
      width:100%;
   height:20px;
   background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
   color:white;
  }
  
#Pro{
     width:0%;
  height:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(33,150,243,1) 50%, rgba(33,150,243,0.9) 50%);
 }
 
#FirstName::selection, #LastName::selection, #FullName::selection, #PSW::selection, #MPSW::selection{
                                                                                                     background:white;
                                                                                               color:black;
                                                                                              }
 
#FirstName, #LastName, #FullName, #PSW, #MPSW{
                                              width:400px;
                                           height:auto;
                                           padding:20px;
                                           background:black;
                                           color:white;
                                           outline:none;
                                           margin:20px 80px;
                                           border:2px solid white;
                                          }
 
#FirstName::placeholder, #LastName::placeholder, #FullName::placeholder, #PSW::placeholder, #MPSW::placeholder{
                                                                                                               user-select:none;
                             }
 
#Register{
          width:200px;
    height:auto;
    padding:20px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    outline:none;
    border:2px solid white;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
   }
   
#Register:hover{
                background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(33,155,243,1) 50%, rgba(33,155,243,0.9) 50%);
    color:white;
    border:2px solid white;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<body>

<div id="Black">

<div id="Prog">
<div id="Pro">0%</div>
</div>

<div id="White">

<form action="http://www.freelancer.com" method="POST">

<input type="text" placeholder=" First Name" id="FirstName"/>

<input type="text" placeholder=" Last Name" id="LastName"/>

<input type="text" placeholder=" Full Name" id="FullName"/>

<input type="text" placeholder=" Type your password" id="PSW"/>

<input type="text" placeholder=" Retype your password" id="MPSW"/>

<input type="submit" value="Register" id="Register"/>

</form>

</div>

<script>
var prog=document.getElementById("Prog");

var pro=document.getElementById("Pro");

var fname=document.getElementById("FirstName");

var lname=document.getElementById("LastName");

var full=document.getElementById("FullName");

var psw0=document.getElementById("PSW");

var mpsw0=document.getElementById("MPSW");

var firstname=document.getElementById("FirstName").value;

var lastname=document.getElementById("LastName").value;

var fullname=document.getElementById("FullName").value;

var psw=document.getElementById("PSW").value;

var mpsw=document.getElementById("MPSW").value;

document.getElementById("FirstName").value="";

document.getElementById("LastName").value="";

document.getElementById("FullName").value="";

document.getElementById("PSW").value="";

document.getElementById("MPSW").value="";

var width=0;

var i;




</script>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the javascript code for the progressbar?

Comment: I don't know the right code for the progressbar. I need the full code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener for the `keypress` event of each of the `input`s to increase the progress by 20% (keypress is only fired when a character is outputted).

You can also add an event listener for the `keydown` event of each of the `input`s and check if the keyCode is 8 (backspace) and if the current length of the value of the `input` is `1` (in which case that character will be deleted) to remove 20% from the progress.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p0kg4sb9/13/embedded/result

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body{
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#Black{
       width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
   }

#White{
       width:600px;
    height:auto;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    color:white;
    margin:100px auto;
   }   
   
#Prog{
      width:100%;
   height:20px;
   background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
   color:white;
  }
  
#Pro{
     width:0%;
  height:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(33,150,243,1) 50%, rgba(33,150,243,0.9) 50%);
 }
 
#FirstName::selection, #LastName::selection, #FullName::selection, #PSW::selection, #MPSW::selection{
                                                                                                     background:white;
                                                                                               color:black;
                                                                                              }
 
#FirstName, #LastName, #FullName, #PSW, #MPSW{
                                              width:400px;
                                           height:auto;
                                           padding:20px;
                                           background:black;
                                           color:white;
                                           outline:none;
                                           margin:20px 80px;
                                           border:2px solid white;
                                          }
 
#FirstName::placeholder, #LastName::placeholder, #FullName::placeholder, #PSW::placeholder, #MPSW::placeholder{
                                                                                                               user-select:none;
                             }
 
#Register{
          width:200px;
    height:auto;
    padding:20px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    outline:none;
    border:2px solid white;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
   }
   
#Register:hover{
                background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(33,155,243,1) 50%, rgba(33,155,243,0.9) 50%);
    color:white;
    border:2px solid white;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<body>

<div id="Black">

<div id="Prog">
<div id="Pro">0%</div>
</div>

<div id="White">

<form action="http://www.freelancer.com" method="POST">

<input type="text" placeholder=" First Name" id="FirstName"/>

<input type="text" placeholder=" Last Name" id="LastName"/>

<input type="text" placeholder=" Full Name" id="FullName"/>

<input type="text" placeholder=" Type your password" id="PSW"/>

<input type="text" placeholder=" Retype your password" id="MPSW"/>

<input type="submit" value="Register" id="Register"/>

</form>

</div>

<script>
var prog=document.getElementById("Prog");

var pro=document.getElementById("Pro");
var progress = 0; 
var firstNameInputted = false;
var lastNameInputted = false;
var fullNameInputted = false;
var pswInputted = false;
var mpswInputted = false;
var firstName = document.getElementById("FirstName");
firstName.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
 if(!firstNameInputted){
   firstNameInputted = true;
    progress += 20;
    pro.textContent = progress + "%";
    pro.style.width = progress + "%";
  }
});
firstName.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 8&&firstName.value.length==1){
     firstNameInputted = false;
      progress -= 20;
    pro.textContent = progress + "%";
    pro.style.width = progress + "%";
   }
});
var lastName = document.getElementById("LastName");
lastName.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
 if(!lastNameInputted){
   lastNameInputted = true;
    progress += 20;
    pro.textContent = progress + "%";
    pro.style.width = progress + "%";
  }
});
lastName.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==8&&lastName.value.length==1){
     lastNameInputted = false;
       progress -= 20;
    pro.textContent = progress + "%";
    pro.style.width = progress + "%";
    }
});
var fullName = document.getElementById("FullName");
fullName.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
 if(!fullNameInputted){
   fullNameInputted = true;
    progress += 20;
    pro.textContent = progress + "%";
    pro.style.width = progress + "%";
  }
});
fullName.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
   if(e.keyCode==8&&fullName.value.length==1){
     fullNameInputted = false;
       progress -= 20;
    pro.textContent = progress + "%";
    pro.style.width = progress + "%";
   }
});
var psw = document.getElementById("PSW");
psw.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
 if(!pswInputted){
   pswInputted = true;
    progress += 20;
    pro.textContent = progress + "%";
    pro.style.width = progress + "%";
  }
});
psw.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==8&&psw.value.length==1){
     pswInputted = false;
       progress -= 20;
    pro.textContent = progress + "%";
    pro.style.width = progress + "%";
    }
});
var mpsw = document.getElementById("MPSW");
mpsw.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
 if(!mpswInputted){
   mpswInputted = true;
    progress += 20;
    pro.textContent = progress + "%";
    pro.style.width = progress + "%";
  }
});
mpsw.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==8&&mpsw.value.length==1){
       mpswInputted = false;
        progress -= 20;
    pro.textContent = progress + "%";
    pro.style.width = progress + "%";
   }
});





</script>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If I input something and then delete the texts from input fields, the progress is not decreasing from the progress bar for each input field. Also when I input 2 characters in a input field the progress adds 20% not in 1 character.